# Uninstall a global package (express) in npm

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to uninstall express 4.x to 3.x. Here is what I currently see in the terminal:

```
npm uninstall express
npm WARN uninstall not installed in /home/johnmlocklear/node_modules: "express"

npm uninstall -g express
npm WARN uninstall not installed in /usr/local/lib/node_modules: "express"

express -V
4.2.0

ls .npm/express
3.0.0  4.2.0  4.4.4

which express
/usr/local/bin/express

ls -lh /usr/local/bin/express
/usr/local/bin/express -> ../lib/node_modules/express-generator/bin/express
```

So I guess I am confused why npm is looking in my home folder for express. Also if I try this with the -g option I get the same error message. I want to either install express completely and I can reinstall the version 3, or is there a way to choose version 3 as the active version?

Comment: It doesn't appear the command at least is from [`express`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/express), but the [`express-generator`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/express-generator).

Comment: Try `npm -g rm express`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
npm install -g express@"3.x.x"
```